# Finding current density?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current

I found (from [here](http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jstiles/220/handouts/Volume%20Current%20Density.pdf)) that current density can be found with the formula: 
$$\vec j= \frac{dI}{ds} \vec a$$
where $s$ is the cross sectional area centred on the point we are considering and with a normal vector in the same direction as the direction of the current , $\vec a$ which is a unit vector.

But I have no idea how to use it? How do we write $I$ in such a way that we can differentiate it with respect to $s$? Any examples, would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take for example a conducting body with an arbitrary shape and volume $V$ connected to a battery that will cause a current flow in the body. You don't know the microscopic structure of the body; so in principle for any point $ \mathbf{r} \in V $ you can have a different value of $I$: $$ I=I(\mathbf{r})=I(x,y,z) $$
Now, take any surface $ \Sigma $ in $V$; for the points $ \mathbf{r} \in \Sigma $, your current is a function of the surface $ \Sigma $, which you can express in parametric form: 
$$ \Sigma = \{ (x',y', z') \in V : x'=x'(u,v), y'=y'(u,v), z'=z'(u,v), \text{for proper values of } u \text{ and } v \} $$ and thus:
$$ I(\Sigma) = I(x'(u,v),y'(u,v),z'(u,v))$$ 
Now you can differentiate the expression of $I$ with respect to the parameters $(u,v)$. For each $\Sigma$ you have different parametric equations, and differentiate gives you the derivative of $I$ with respect to that particular $ \Sigma$.

That's how I would see differentiating a function with respect to a surface; but I think the formula you reported has a bit of notation abuse and makes much more sense if you use:
$$ \mathbf{J}= \rho\mathbf{v} $$ where $\rho$ is the volumetric charge density of the body and $v$ is the speed of the charges flowing in the direction $\mathbf{a}$. With this expression of $\mathbf{J}$ is easier to calculate the derivative.

Comment: Is it possible to show some equivlence between $\vec J =\rho \vec v$ and my expression $\vec j=\frac{dI}{dS} \vec a$?

Comment: Yes, consider $dI=dq/dt$ and multiply and divide the right side of your equattion by $dr$, now you have: $$ \mathbf{J}=\frac{dq}{dV}\frac{dr}{dt}\mathbf{a}= \rho \mathbf{v}$$.

Comment: One more thing, the velocity $\vec v$ is this the averge drift veloiocty of the particles in an infintismal cube surrounding the point we are considering?

Comment: The units of $\mathbf{J} $ are $A/m^2$, so you take a point $\mathbf{r}$ in your conductor and consider a small surface around $\mathbf{r}$ with a normal vector $\mathbf{a}$. $\mathbf{v}$ is the component of the drift velocity in the direction $\mathbf{a}$.

Comment: How do you carry out the differentiation w.r.t. to the parameters, and how are they bringing in the dimensions of a surface?

Comment: Ex. $$ \frac{\partial I}{\partial u}= \sum_i^3 \frac{\partial I}{\partial x'_i}\frac{\partial x'_i}{\partial u}  $$ and in an analogous way for the other partial derivative. That could be useful for practical calculus purposes. Formally, I think the definition of derivative with respect to a surface you posted in your answer is a much better one. (That's why I voted it +1).

Answer (score 1):

That is a limiting procedure pretty much similar to the definition of derivative. Fix the point $x$ where you want to compute the current density and consider a small disk $D$ centred at that point. There will be a certain current $I(D)$ flowing across this disk. As this disk shrinks on to the point, the ratio
$$\frac{\text dI}{\text d S}\Big\vert_x:=\lim_{\sigma(D)\to0} \frac{I(D)}{\sigma(D)},$$
where $\sigma(D)$ is the surface of the disk, will represent the density current at the point $x$, modulo the velocity vector $\mathbf a$. Observe that there is a geometric factor involved in this which depends how the (normal to the) surface is oriented w.r.t. $\mathbf a$ at the point $x$, which turns out to be the cosine of the angle between these two vectors.

Comment: Hi is it possible to add an example